# Convert URL.Query (map of slices) to struct golang

Tags: go, struct

It would be awesome to have a straight forward mapping from the standard library [URL.Query()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.Query) to an struct.

`Query()` returns a map like:
`map[a:[aaaa] b:[bbbb] c:[cccc]]`

The struct looks like:

```
type Thing struct {
    A    string
    B    string
    C    string
}
```

- I've no idea why URL.Query returns a map with array elements inside tough. (well.. I know [why](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values) but a `GET` is not likely to have duplicated params)

Comment: a GET is --not likely to-- can have duplicated params. In which cases it is translated to a slice of values. Have you looked to gorilla.schema package ? I believe it can do the job.

Comment: In my case I would be fine and keen to have one exception fired in case of duplicates. I gave a look into gorilla.schema, it's awesome! thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Please find below the complete example of parsing get query params directly in a golang struct and then sending the struct back as response

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/gorilla/schema"
)

var decoder  = schema.NewDecoder()

type EmployeeStruct struct {
    MemberId         string `schema:"memberId"`
    ActivityType     string `schema:"activityType"`
    BusinessUnitCode int    `schema:"businessUnitCode"`
}

func GetEmployee(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var employeeStruct EmployeeStruct

    err := decoder.Decode(&employeeStruct, r.URL.Query())
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error in GET parameters : ", err)
    } else {
        log.Println("GET parameters : ", employeeStruct)
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(employeeStruct)
}

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/GetEmployee", GetEmployee)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux))
}
```

Steps to execute & Test (Assuming you are saving above code in **employee.go**) :

**Step 1** : go run employee.go

**Step 2** : Open in browser http://localhost:8080/GetEmployee?memberId=123&activityType=Call&businessUnitCode=56

**Step 3** : You should get below response in browser window

```
{
    "MemberId": "123",
    "ActivityType": "Call",
    "BusinessUnitCode": 56
}
```

**Step 4** : On console you should see below

```
GET parameters :  {123 Call 56}
```

Answer (score 3):

example:

```
filters={"reference":["docker.io/library/alpine:latest"]}
```

need url encode to:

```
filters=%7B%22reference%22%3A%5B%22docker.io%2Flibrary%2Falpine%3Alatest%22%5D%7D
```

and could use `"github.com/gorilla/schema"`

```golang
    query := struct {
        All     bool
        Filters map[string][]string `schema:"filters"`
        Digests bool
        Filter  string 
    }{}
    decoder := schema.NewDecoder()
    decoder.Decode(&query, r.URL.Query())
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @mh-cbon [gorilla schema](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/schema) is the ultimate solution here.

Instead for obtaining the queryParams from the URL attribute.

```
func handleRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    queryString := r.URL.Query()
    //...parsing the Values -> map[string][]string
}
```

The approach of gorilla schema is to ship `r.PostForm` to the decode function.

```
func handleRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := decoder.Decode(person, r.PostForm)
    //...using reflect each struct's property can be called using 
    // the PostForm(url string, data url.Values) signature

    fmt.Print(person.GoodJobGorilla)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using [ggicci/httpin](https://github.com/ggicci/httpin)

**Disclaimer**: I'm the creator and maintainer of this package.

**httpin** helps you easily decoding HTTP request data from

- **Query parameters**, e.g. `?name=john&is_member=true`
- **Headers**, e.g. `Authorization: xxx`
- **Form data**, e.g. `username=john&password=******`
- **JSON/XML Body**, e.g. `POST {"name":"john"}`
- **Path variables**, e.g. `/users/{username}`
- **File uploads**

#### How to use?

```golang
type ListUsersInput struct {
    Page     int  `in:"query=page"`
    PerPage  int  `in:"query=per_page"`
    IsMember bool `in:"query=is_member"`
}

func ListUsers(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    input := r.Context().Value(httpin.Input).(*ListUsersInput)

    if input.IsMember {
        // Do sth.
    }
    // Do sth.
}
```

**httpin** is:

- **well documented**: at https://ggicci.github.io/httpin/
- **well tested**: coverage over 98%
- **open integrated**: with [net/http](https://ggicci.github.io/httpin/integrations/http), [go-chi/chi](https://ggicci.github.io/httpin/integrations/gochi), [gorilla/mux](https://ggicci.github.io/httpin/integrations/gorilla), [gin-gonic/gin](https://ggicci.github.io/httpin/integrations/gin), etc.
- **extensible** (advanced feature): by adding your custom directives. Read [httpin - custom directives](https://ggicci.github.io/httpin/directives/custom) for more details.
- **awesome mentioned**: https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#forms

Answer (score 1):

Just parse the string to URL and after you can use the lib `github.com/gorilla/schema` to parse it :)

```golang
// Example to parse querystring to struct
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/url"

    "github.com/gorilla/schema"
)

type URLParams struct {
    Code  string `schema:"code"`
    State string `schema:"state"`
}

func main() {
    var (
        params  URLParams
        decoder = schema.NewDecoder()
    )
    p := "https://www.redirect-url.com?code=CODE&state=RANDOM_ID"

    u, _ := url.Parse(p)

    err := decoder.Decode(&params, u.Query())
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error in Decode parameters : ", err)
    } else {
        log.Printf("Decoded parameters : %#v\n", params)
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/CmuPhdKh6Yg

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is using [Echo](https://echo.labstack.com/guide/binding/#struct-tag-binding), `query` struct tag will be useful for this case.

#### Example Struct

```
type struct Name {
    FirstName string `query:"first_name"`
    LastName string `query:"last_name"`
}
```

#### Example Query Param

```
?first_name="shahriar"&last_name="sazid"
```

#### Code

```
var name Name
err := c.Bind(&name); if err != nil {
    return c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, "bad request")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the graceful package of [Echo](https://github.com/labstack/echo).

I write some codes as an example, with self-explanatory comments

```
 package main

 import (
     "log"
     "github.com/labstacks/echo"
)

// Declare your struct with form: "" tag
type Employee struct {
    MemberId         string `form:"memberId"`
    ActivityType     string `form:"activityType"`
    BusinessUnitCode int    `form:"businessUnitCode"`
}

// Your handlers should look like this method 
// Which takes an echo.Context and returns an error
func GetEmployee(ctx echo.Context) error{
    var employee Employee
    // With Bind, you can get the Post Body or query params from http.Request
    // that is wrapped by echo.Context here 
    if err := ctx.Bind(&employee);err != nil {
        return err
    } 

    // now you can use your struct , e.g
    return ctx.json(200, employee.MemberId)
}

// now use the handler in your main function or anywhere you need
func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    e.Get("/employee", GetEmployee)
    log.Fatal(e.Start(":8080"))
}
```

Comment: I think this is the right link for the related doc https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/labstack/echo/v4#DefaultBinder.Bind But, truth is, IDK, which Binder the context uses and otherwise. So I think it might exist a better link.